# Input.Mouseposition does not work with photon for some reason

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon-pun

I am trying to make the gun facing the mouse with this code

```
private void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (view.IsMine)
    {
        mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time > nextTimeToFire)
        {
        
            GameObject bullet1 = Instantiate(bullet, firepoint.position, firepoint.rotation);
            Rigidbody2D rb2 = bullet1.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
            rb2.AddForce(firepoint.right * 50f, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
            ScreenManager.Instance.ScreenShake(10f, 0.1f);
            Destroy(bullet1, 20f);
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f/fireRate;
        
        
        }
        Vector2 lookDir = mousePos - rb1.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(lookDir.y, lookDir.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(transform.rotation.x, transform.rotation.y, angle);
    }
     
}
```

it worked before i was using photon but now it doesnt, anyone help

Comment: You have not set the distance in screen to world point.  If it was working before.. check that you dont have multiple cameras in the scene.